# How to implement video viewing in a browser that minimally buffers data and allows seeking (like youtube)?

Tags: amazon-s3, html5-video

There are similar questions out there, but since my case is specific, I'm going to ask this for my own purposes.

I have a subscription service where users can watch educational videos on my site. Currently the site uses S3 and HTML5 video to serve videos.

However, this means that that whole video is loaded at once, regardless of how much the user watches. I have the feeling that I could significantly reduce my S3 transfer costs if I could find a way to only use MINIMAL buffering, and seeking the youtube does.

I'm not sure what would be the way to implement this however. I don't know if S3 and/or html5 video support this type of experience.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I get html5 video and s3 storage to only get new video data "when needed"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39989678/how-do-i-get-html5-video-and-s3-storage-to-only-get-new-video-data-when-needed)

Comment: Actually that post is mine, and the difference is I guess subtle. This question deals with how to implement it in general (not necessarily using html5 and S3). The other was my first question and was meant to discover if any of this is possible with htm5 and S3.